# Solution to the linear differential equation of order $n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we study the solution to the equation: $$a_{n}y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+...+a_{0}y=0$$ where $a_{i}$ is real coefficient $i\in \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$. We know that: if the characteristic polynomial $a_{n}x^{n}+...+a_{0}=0$ has a root $x=r$ appearing $k$-times then $y=e^{rt}, y=te^{rt},...,y=t^{k-1}e^{rt}$ are solutions with respect to $x=r$!

Why can we think that we need to multiply $t,...,t^{k-1}$ to $e^{rt}$ to get $k$ linearly independent functions?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: It means that if the equation $a_{n}x^{n}+...+a_{o}=0$ has a root x=r apearing k-times, then we get k-linearly independent functions having the forms: $e^{rt},...,t^{k-1}e^{rt}$ why can we know it that has those forms? and whether we has another form solutions for the case x=r?.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that for any $b_0,...,b_{n-1}$ the differential equation has a unique solution satisfying $y^{(k)}(0) = b_k$ for $k=0,...,n-1$.

Let $y_0,...,y_{n-1}$ be the solutions corresponding to the collection of initial
conditions $(1,0,0,...,0),(0,1,0,...,0),....,(0,....,0,1)$.

It should be clear that any solution can be written as a linear combination of $y_0,...,y_{n-1}$ (the linear multipliers can be found by evaluating the
derivatives at $0$),
and 
furthermore, if $\sum_k \alpha_k y_k = 0$,
then we have $\sum_k \alpha_k y_k(0) = 0$ and so $\alpha_k = 0$. In other words, the $y_k$ are linearly independent.

In particular, the dimension of the space of solutions is $n$ and hence
**any** collection of $n$ linearly independent solutions can be used to represent any solution of the differential equation in a unique way.

If the characteristic equation has roots $r_1,...,r_l$ with multiplicities
$m_1,...,m_l$ (and $\sum_k m_k = n$, of course), then we can show that
the functions $t \mapsto t^i e^{r_jt}$ for $j=1,...,l$ and $i=0,...,m_i-1$
are linearly independent and are solutions to the differential equation.
Since there are $n$ of them, they span the same space as $y_0,...,y_{n-1}$
and so any solution can be written in terms of either the $ y_k$ or the
$t \mapsto t^i e^{r_jt}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you split the solution as $y(t)=e^{rt}u(t)$, then you can confirm that the equation transforms to
$$
b_nu^{(n)}+...+b_ku^{(k)}=0
$$
where a family of solutions is obtained from $u^{(k)}=0$. These are the polynomials of degree smaller $k$, with basis $u(t)=1,t,...,t^{k-1}$, giving a solution system $e^{rt},te^{rt},...,t^{k-1}e^{rt}$ for $y(t)$.